# pandas groupby multiple functions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want summarize the `integer_transaction` by `EMP_NAME`.

1. why does my first command fail? How to modify it
2. in case of the second command how to avoid the warning?
3. Is there any way to put `EMP_NAME` in a column instead of the index

I want output

```
Emp_name Count Sum
a           2   1
b           1   0


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'EMP_NAME': ["a", "a", "b"], 'integer_transaction': [0, 1, 0]})

x=df.groupby(['EMP_NAME'])['integer_transaction'].agg({'Frequency_count': count, 'Frequency_Sum': np.sum})

x=df.groupby(['EMP_NAME'])['integer_transaction'].agg({'Frequency_count': np.size, 'Frequency_Sum': np.sum})

FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
 df.groupby(['EMP_NAME'])['integer_transaction'].agg(["count", "sum"])

          count  sum
EMP_NAME            
a             2    1
b             1    0
```

If you really want, you can rename the columns using an additional `.rename("count": "Frequency_count", "sum": "Frequency_sum")`.

Just for reference, the following also works perfectly fine:

```
x=df.groupby(['EMP_NAME'])['integer_transaction'].agg({'Frequency_count': "count", 'Frequency_Sum': np.sum})
x
__main__:1: FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
Out[26]: 
          Frequency_count  Frequency_Sum
EMP_NAME                                
a                       2              1
b                       1              0
```

Note how `count` is quoted.

```
x=df.groupby(['EMP_NAME'])['integer_transaction'].agg({'Frequency_count': np.size, 'Frequency_Sum': np.sum})
x
__main__:1: FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
Out[27]: 
          Frequency_count  Frequency_Sum
EMP_NAME                                
a                       2              1
b                       1              0
```

The warnings you get just tell you that this functionality will be removed in the future, so they should probably not be used. However, they do produce the correct answer.

To move the index to the column, try

```
df.groupby(['EMP_NAME'])['integer_transaction'].agg(["count", "sum"]).reset_index()
  EMP_NAME  count  sum
0        a      2    1
1        b      1    0
```

Comment: any way to modify the function so that i don't get the warning?

Comment: This is not advisable, as the code will break in future versions. Why not just use my first solution? If need be, you can rename the columns afterwards.